# CQL3 order by statement is ordering uppercase strings first

Tags: cassandra, cql3

Im finding that my CQL3 order by statements are returning strange results, where any strings starting with uppercase letters are ordered first, and then the lowercase strings are ordered second.

Heres an example table:

```
CREATE TABLE tester 
(rowkey text, colname text, colvalue text, primary key (rowkey, colname)) 
WITH COMPACT STORAGE;
```

If I populate it with some test data and run the following query this is what I get:

Query:

```
SELECT * FROM tester WHERE rowkey = 'test' ORDER BY colname ASC
```

Results:

```
rowkey | colname | colvalue
-------+---------+---------
test   | ABC     | blah
test   | Abc     | blah
test   | BBC     | blah
test   | abc     | blah
test   | bbC     | blah
test   | bbc     | blah
```

I cant see how that would be expected behavior. Does anyone know why its ordering it like that and how to achieve a more sensible order?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your columns are being sorted in lexicographical order, in which upper case characters have precedence over lower case.

Comment: So is there a way to sort the columns ABC, Abc, abc, BBC, bbC, bbc?

Comment: Maybe Im missing something, but it seems more like a binary representation sort order that my columns are being sorted by, rather than lexicographical.

Comment: It's helpful to remember that not everyone uses the same characters or has the same ordering, which helps to explain why it may not make obvious sense.

Comment: Creating a case-insensitive ordering is possible but has so far not attracted much developer interest. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-4245